# Format not working using xlsxwriter in odoo

Tags: odoo, xlsxwriter

i am working in odoo 14 and from web page. On button click i want to generate excel file. For this i have write code in controller using xlsxwriter.

But when i run code excel file generate but format not implemented.

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'font_size': '12px'})
head = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'bold': True, 'font_size': '20px'})
txt = workbook.add_format({'font_size': '10px'})
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
format_qty = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format_amount = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0'})
```

Also showing following error when open file.

```
Removed Part: /xl/styles.xml part with XML error.  (Styles) Load error. Line 2, column 297.
Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
```

Comment: The font size should be an integer like 12 and not a string like ‘12px’. The string is probably okay but not the ‘px’ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'font_size' should be integer

Do it like this

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 12})
head = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'bold': True, 'font_size': 20})
txt = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 10})
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
format_qty = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format_amount = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0'})
```